# installing numpy and pip for python 2.7.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pip

I want to install numpy, I put "pip install numpy", then(I copied someone else's error report):

```
C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\jon\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_jon\\numpy\\setup.py';   
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\jon\appdata\local\temp\pip-qnynnf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed 
Error:  --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\jon\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_jon\numpyStoring  debug log for failure in C:\Users\jon\pip\pip.log
```

They said : 
Their solutions were to make sure you have an up-to-date version of setuptools. I installed Python 2.7.9 from the main website, and it comes with both setuptools and pip ready to go. Plus I made sure my system had them installed by checking pip list.

I tried to upgrade my pip, but I can't. Following are the snaps attached:

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

I'm using Windows system, 64-bit, python 2.7.6.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

py -2.7 -m pip install numpy

Basically you just put the python version and then instruct the pip module to install what you need.
Source:
https://docs.python.org/2/installing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your first command; it's confusingly long.
Try

```
pip install numpy
```

and be done with it.

---

As for upgrading pip: try

```
pip install --upgrade --force pip
```

I find the suggested command in the error message a bit confusing; no need to use python -m pip.

Note that it probably will matter little, going from version 7.1.0 to 7.1.2.

Comment: thanks!! I use "easy_install pip" to upgrade pip..... I'm installing scipy now, it seems that there is still some problem.....

Comment: Well, scipy wasn't in your question. Did numpy install ok? Please don't change your question into a scipy installation problem, since then this answer doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Open Anaconda Prompt and just use 
 pip install numpy

If you will be asked to upgrade pip command, just write

python -m pip install --upgrade pip